# C# Class Library connect to WebSocket

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-core

I have a Class Library project on .Net Core. And there I want to connect to WebSocket

I know how to connect in API-project where I can use Startup.cs. And there I config services via `services.AddWebSocketManager();` and configure `IApplicationBuilder` via `app.UseWebSockets()`

But how to do it via Class Library project?

It's possible?

Comment: So are you trying to execute something without `Main` method?

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya Yes, I want to just write dll where I'll be connect to websocket

Comment: But you need to consume that library somewhere, as like `NetGain`. `NetGain` is also a high performance websocket server library.